# Repair Fedora GRUB after grub2-mkconfig gone wrong

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, grub2-mkconfig

I was trying to enable fractional scaling in Fedora 39 using ChatGPT and he recommended the following:

```
# NVIDIA's proprietary driver requires DRM KMS to be disabled for Wayland to work. 
# Edit the file /etc/default/grub and ensure the parameter nvidia-drm.modeset=1 is not set. 
# If it is, change it to nvidia-drm.modeset=0 or remove it. Then update the grub configuration with:
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

I did so and ran the command, only to find my GRUB Menu only showing me the Windows Boot Manager. I can boot into Windows without problems, but now GRUB cannot find Fedora.

**Solution I am trying**

I created a USB bootable drive with Fedora and, after doing a quick Google search (and more ChatGPT, besides being the culprit), I stumbled upon the following plausible solution (with my `/dev` partitions already inputted):

```
# Mount the root filesystem
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/root

# Mount the EFI partition
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt/root/boot/efi

# Bind-mount the virtual filesystems
for dir in /dev /proc /sys /run; do
    sudo mount --bind $dir /mnt/root$dir
done
```

With that `/mnt` set up, I run `sudo chroot /mnt`, which worked as intented. I edited my `/etc/default/grub` file back to how it originally was, and then I tried to re-generate my `grub.cfg` file again with the command: `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`. Nevertheless, I keep getting the following error: `/usr/sbin/grub2-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).`. I have tried several combinations of the mounting procedure without success, such as this one:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/root/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/root/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /dev/shm /mnt/root/dev/shm
sudo mount --bind /dev/disk /mnt/root/dev/disk
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/root/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/root/sys
sudo mount --bind /run /mnt/root/run
```

I also tried to follow [this guide](https://thomas-leister.de/en/repair-fedora-efi-bootloader/), which attempts to solve a similar problem, and there, the command works. I don't know what I could be doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

**Output of lsblk**

```
Device             Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048     845151    843104 411.7M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2    845824     878591     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p3    878592  783736831 782858240 373.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p4 994082816  997033681   2950866   1.4G Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme0n1p5 997033984 1000214527   3180544   1.5G Windows recovery environmen
/dev/nvme0n1p6 783736832  785833983   2097152     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p7 785833984  977303551 191469568  91.3G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p8 977303552  994080767  16777216     8G Linux swap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trials and errors, I managed to find a solution for my problem. I am leaving it here, in case anyone stumbles upon this problem.

My system turned out to use BRTFS subvolumes and the steps to mount the necessary partitions are different for this type of filesystem. This is why I could not follow the steps in [this guide](https://thomas-leister.de/en/repair-fedora-efi-bootloader/). My particular situation had an EFI partition in `/dev/nvme0n1p6` and the `root` and `boot` (I know, very odd) partition in `/dev/nvme0n1p7`. In the latter, there is a root subfolder that has the classic linux folders (`bin`, `home`, `opt`, etc.).

Go to the section **Using the GRUB2 boot prompt** for the solution that worked for me. For the sake of completeness, the next part explains how to execute the command `grub2-mkconfig` in a chrooted system that uses BRTFS subvolumes properly.

**Chroot into a system with BRTFS subvolumes**

By following [this lifesaver post](https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/how-to-chroot-a-system-that-uses-btrfs-subvolumes/71213) and trying out many combinations of mounting procedures out of desperation, I managed to chroot into my system correctly:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/sysimage
sudo mount -o subvol=root /dev/nvme0n1p7 /mnt/sysimage
sudo mount -o bind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev
sudo mount -o bind /proc /mnt/sysimage/proc
sudo mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sysimage/sys
sudo mount -o bind /sys/firmware/efi/efivars /mnt/sysimage/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p6 /mnt/sysimage/boot/efi
sudo chroot /mnt/sysimage
```

*Note:* In case you end up without network connection inside the chrooted system, you can follow the steps detailed in [the same guide](https://thomas-leister.de/en/repair-fedora-efi-bootloader/).

After this, I could perform the following commands inside my chrooted system:

```
dnf reinstall shim-* grub2-efi-* grub2-common
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
sync && exit
```

To `umount` everything, just do:

```
sudo umount /mnt/sysimage/sys
sudo umount /mnt/sysimage/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sysimage/dev
sudo umount /mnt/sysimage/boot/efi
sudo umount /mnt/sysimage/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
sudo umount /mnt/sysimage
```

Doing that, I no longer got the error `/usr/sbin/grub2-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?)`, after running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`, which was the original purpose of my question. Nevertheless, executing that command did not bring my Fedora back to the grub, even after trying these commands that I found on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Tamal/73e65bfb0e883e438310c5fe81c5de14):

```
# Check BIOS boot details [ Note: this command won't work if you are inside chroot. ]
efibootmgr -v
# In case you need to create new entry in BIOS
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/nvme0n1p1 -p 1 -L Fedora -l '\EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi' # or, shimx64.efi
```

**Using the GRUB2 boot prompt**

The real solution ended up being on this post on Fedora's main documentation, [Using the GRUB2 boot prompt](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/grub2-bootloader/#_using_the_grub2_boot_prompt). I booted my PC, pressed `Esc`, got into the BIOS Menu and selected Fedora. Of course, there was not going to be anything there, so it got me to the classic black `grub>` screen. There, I executed the following commands:

```
# Show all partitions
grub> ls
(hd0) (hd1) (hd0,gpt1) ...

# Try out every one of them until you find your EFI partition and your root partition. Mine was (hd2,gpt6) and (hd2,gpt7), respectively.
grub> ls (hd2,gpt6)/ # Had an EFI folder
grub> ls (hd2,gpt7)/ # Inside was the root folder and inside that, my beloved Fedora

# You set root to your EFI partition, mine being (hd2,gpt6)
grub> set root=(hd2,gpt6)

# And the following commands starting with the root partition, mine being (hd2,gpt7)
grub> linux (hd2,gpt7)/root/boot/vmlinuz-6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64 root=/dev/nvme0n1p7 ro rootflags=subvol=root
grub> initrd (hd2,gpt7)/root/boot/initramfs-6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64.img

# This command will finish the session and will boot up the chosen kernel and RAM filesystem
grub> boot
```

*Note:* You need to find the exact path where the kernel you want to boot up (`vmlinuz-...`) and the RAM filesystem (`initramfs-...-.img`) are. For this, you can just do `ls <your root partition>/root/` and begin navigating folder by folder. For me, `ls (hd2,gpt7)/root/boot/` showed me all the kernels and RAM filesystems I had. I chose the latest one, with the suffix `6.6.9-200.fc39.x86_64`. Also, notice the part `root=/dev/nvme0n1p7 ro rootflags=subvol=root` in the `linux` command. This is crucial for a BRTFS system; without it the system won't boot up correctly. Naturally, `root=` has to be set to your own `root` partition, while the rest should remain the same.

**Inside your system**

By now, you should have booted up your old lost system. Inside, I opened up a terminal and executed the following commands to recover my `grub`, so that I didn't have to do the above process everytime I wanted to log into Fedora.

```
# Back up your current GRUB configuration as a precaution:
sudo cp /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg.bak

# Regenerate the GRUB configuration file with:
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg

# Reinstall GRUB to ensure it's properly installed on the EFI partition:
sudo grub2-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Fedora
```

I then rebooted my PC and, for some odd reason, I did not find Fedora listed on my BIOS Boot Menu (which had not happened until now, it always showed it, except that it only led to the `grub>` screen). I logged into my Windows, rebooted again, went into the BIOS Boot Menu, and now Fedora was there. I selected it and my PC booted directly into it, without going to the `grub` menu, which is indeed odd, but it definitely suits me as-is so far. I can now log into my Fedora, without problems.

*As always, be careful executing any of these commands and double-check for your particular system and configuration.*